# Is there a way to click on a specific spot on an element?

Tags: android, appium-android

Given this  method (http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/actions/click/) only clicks the center of an element, are there means/methods to click on a specific spot on an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current XY coordinate and then compare these coordinates with your SPECIFIC spot.
Sample:

```
element.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                if(event.getX()>a && event.getY()<b) {
                    //Your code goes here
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
});
```

where a and b are specific spot in terms of X and Y axis respectively.